# Search In Js Array Given Two Variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Given the example array

```
array =
[
 ["name1", ["blue", "yellow", "pink"], "id"],
 ["name2", ["green", "orange"], "id"],
 ["nameN", ["purple", "black", "white", "red"], "id"],
];
```

Is it possible, in (vanilla) Js, to efficiently get `name` and `id` of the ones matching two given colors (let's say `red` and `black`)?

Comment: `array.filter(([, colours]) => ["red", "black"].every((colour) => colours.includes(colour))).map(([name, , id]) => ({ name, id }));`?

Comment: Hi Zytu, yes its possible, you should do some research and try to attempt this yourself. When you have a question with your attempt come back an ask that. SO isn't a place where we will write the entire solution from scratch. You are probably being down voted because you didn't provide an example for us to work off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to get a certain element based on condition and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check array includes a certain value.

```js
let array = [
  ["name1", ["blue", "yellow", "pink"], "id"],
  ["name2", ["green", "orange"], "id"],
  ["nameN", ["purple", "black", "white", "red"], "id"],
];

let color = 'orange';

let [name, colors, id] = array.find(a => a[1].includes(color));

console.log(name, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **reduce** also :

```js
const arr = [
  ['name1', ['blue', 'yellow', 'pink'], 'id'],
  ['name2', ['green', 'orange'], 'id'],
  ['nameN', ['purple', 'black', 'white', 'red'], 'id'],
];

const getNameAndIdByColor = (color) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, [name, colors, id]) => (colors.includes(color) ? { ...acc, [color]: { name, id } } : acc),
    {},
  );

console.log('getNameAndIdByColor:', getNameAndIdByColor('red'));
```